# React installation error while running command: npx create-react-app my-app

Tags: reactjs

I want to start my React application but after entering:
`npx create-react-app my-app`,
it's showing me:

> Error: spawn UNKNOWN
> errno: -4094,
> code: 'UNKNOWN',
> syscall: 'spawn'

Please check screenshot:
[image: Aborting installation. Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug: Error: spawn UNKNOWN at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11) at Object.spawn (node:child_process:689:9) at spawn (C:\Users\VAIBHAV\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24) at C:\Users\VAIBHAV\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:383:19 at new Promise () at install (C:\Users\VAIBHAV\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:334:10) at C:\Users\VAIBHAV\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:461:16 at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) { errno: -4094, code: 'UNKNOWN', syscall: 'spawn']

Comment: Looks like a problem with node to spawn a process, what is your node version?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and try again.

If the problem persists, try to install the create-react-app script using

```
npm i -g create-react-app
```

and create the app without the npx prefix.

Comment: same problem , still showing me the same error

Answer (score 0):

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10670) on `create-react-app` repository.

Some users are claiming that they fixed this problem by **uninstalling their antivirus**.

I suggest you could try that.

Comment: yes , it worked now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

1. Uninstall node
2. Remove `C:/Users/[username]/AppData/Roaming/npm` and
   `C:/Users/[username]/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules`
3. Remove `C:/Users/[username]/.npmrc` and `C:/Users/[username]/.node_repl_history`